# Missing SKU field in the "New Product" form

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I've recently started working with Magento and I'm facing a pretty basic problem that I can't manage to figure out.
When creating a new product, from the admin page, Catalog -> Products -> New Product, I'm being redirected to a form. After completing the required fields, I receive an error message:

*The value of attribute "sku" must be set*

Which is a problem, as I don't have any SKU field in my form. I've looked for this problem, without any result, and I found out that SKU should be somewhere between Product Name and Price. Unfortunately, that's not my case.

Any ideas what should I do in this case? 
Thank you!

P.S. My version of Magento is the latest one, 2.2.3.

Edit 1:
This is a screenshot of my form and error:
[image: screneshot]

Edit 2:
This is a screenshot of my default Attribute Set:
[image]

Comment: can you put a link here to a screen shot for your form, this will help figure out what you missed

Comment: @zexperto-WISAMHAKIM Sure, I've edited my question.

Comment: did you try to check if the SKU is exist in the [Product Attributes], to double check it go to [store->attributes->product] search for SKU in attribute code column, if you found it -> go to [store->attributes->attribute set] and be sure that the SKU is added to "default" attribute set. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @zexperto-WISAMHAKIM Unfortunately, it is present in both places. You can find a screenshot in the question. I've also tried changing it's initial position on that list, but it keeps being ignored. Btw, thank you for your time!